# ConfigFactor.load changes inside a single ActorSystem resulting to different application.config being read

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, akka, config

I am using [sbt pack-plugin](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack) to create an executable scala application with all its dependency jars. My application has an *application.config* file from which I load all the configurations for my application (serverIp, ports, ...) using [typesafe's config lib](https://github.com/typesafehub/config). My application has a dependency which also has its default *application.config* but it is defined in its code that it will read the (akka.actor.ExtendedActorSystem).(akka.actor.ActorSystem.Settings).config. It works fine and it reads the values I defined in my *application.conf* when I run my application using **sbt run** but when I package my application using **sbt pack**, it does not read my *application.conf*, instead it reads the default values in its *application.conf*.

Is it possible to force the dependency jar on reading my application.conf when I package it? What I'm thinking right now is to remove the application.conf in the dependency jar but I have no idea how to do it or if it is possible to run it without encountering error. Is there a better solution?

This is how i created the actor of dependency jar. The config values differ for someDependencyActor and anActorInMyProject even though their both in the same ActorSystem.

```
   def startActorSystem(): Unit = {
          val system = ActorSystem("myAppSystem")

          //actorRef to an actor in dependency jar
          val someDependencyActor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SomeDependencyActor]), "someDependencyActor")

          ...
          val anActorInMyProject = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[AnActorInMyProject], "anActorInMyProject")
          //other declartions of actors

   }
```

Dependency classes:

```
   class SomeDependencyActor extends Actor {

          val config = Settings(context.system).config
          ....
   }
```

Settings class in dependency:

```
   class SettingsImpl(val config: Config) extends Extension

   object Settings extends ExtensionId[SettingsImpl] with ExtensionIdProvider {

     override def lookup = Settings

     override def createExtension(system: ExtendedActorSystem) =
       new SettingsImpl(system.settings.config)

     override def get(system: ActorSystem): SettingsImpl = super.get(system)
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The *ConfigFactory.load* output does not change. *Typesafe config lib* actually merges all *application.conf, application.json, etc..* and it allows duplicate keys but retain the last value it found as mentioned [here](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#features-of-hocon). Now I need to find out how the order of merging is determined so my application's application.conf values will be the one loaded.